# Sorting Date mm/dd/yyyy field from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I'm currently getting data from an API and I'm coming across a problem when trying to sort the data in the client side view, by date.

This is the data I'm receiving (about 20+ but I'm giving one example with some sample data filled in)

```
address: "1212 Test Ave"
address2: ""
checkNumber : ""
city: "La Grange"
country: ""
email: "test-email@yahoo.com"
firstName: "John"
id: "103138"
lastName: "Dough"
middleName: ""
organization: ""
partnerId: "108765.1"
paymentAmount: "$5.00 "
paymentDate: "7/30/2015"
paymentType: "CASH"
phoneNumber: "(999)999-9999"
spouseFirstName: ""
spouseLastName: ""
spouseTitle: ""
state: "IL"
title: "Mr. & Mrs."
zipCode: "60525-2544"
```

There is 20+ of these in an array called "contributions".
How would one sort this array by paymentDate "mm/dd/yyyy".  Obviously it would be year sorted first, then month, then day.

I have seen code that somewhat does this but I'm having trouble implementing it from an array that isn't solely an array of dates.

It also does not sort the days correctly, just months/year.  The years is a separate array that I pulled all the dates out of for a different purpose.

```
this.years.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
```

But I am trying to sort the entire array listed in the first code block by date.

If anyone could help me or guide me in the right direction, that would be a massive help!

Thanks!

Additional Information using @mplungjan method.  This is the output of it all when sent through to the table.

[image: Picture Of Table After Date Sorted]

Comment: `contributions.sort(function (a, b) { return new Date(a.paymentDate).getDate() - new Date(b.paymentDate).getDate(); });`

Comment: It seems as if this is only sorting them by day and not by year, month, then day.  However, it did help me understand how the sorting portion of specific parts of a date work.  The getDate is grabbing only the current day and thats why its sorting by Day only.

Comment: That is highly unlikely assuming your date is parsable as it is.

Comment: I edited my post with an image of what it looks like.

Comment: My mistake: you need .getTime() instead of getDate()

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you, your answer works perfectly for me and I still now understand why!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You are welcome. I posted an actual answer too

Comment: I know it's an old post, but: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59349493/11698825 - see this first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sort needs date.getTime()-date.getTime()

In this case you can leave off the getTime since it will be used anyway

```js
var contributions = [
  {paymentDate: "9/2/2014"},
  {paymentDate: "9/7/2014"},
  {paymentDate: "10/8/2015"},
  {paymentDate: "1/9/2014"},
  {paymentDate: "3/9/2015"}
]
contributions.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.paymentDate) - new Date(b.paymentDate)
})
console.log(contributions)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy-to-understand solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contributions.length; i++) {
    var dateI = new Date(contributions[i].paymentDate);
    for (var j = i + 1; j < contributions.length; j++) {
        var dateJ = new Date(contributions[j].paymentDate);
        if (dateI > dateJ) {
            var aux = contributions[i];
            contributions[i] = contributions[j];
            contributions[j] = aux;
            dateI = dateJ;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want an already existent solution, then:

```
contributions.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.paymentDate) - new Date(b.paymentDate);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is VERY informative.  I can see how its working now, however from the answer someone gave above, it seems that that method with the getDate only sorts the current date.  and yours gives me an error (left hand and right hand arithmatic operation must be of type 'any'.  And I'd need it to sort by year then month, then day.

Comment: @AlexLiosatos there were some typos in my answer. I have edited my answer. It works for me. Can you give me a sample data for contributions where my code fails to sort? Can you specify whether the first or the second approach failed? If there is a problem, we will fix it. But I will need some information to do that.